# Flutter Web: Expected a value of type 'Element', but got one of type legacyJavascriptObject

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, google-chrome

everyone. This is an error I'm seeing when loading my flutter web app in chrome:

```
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
```

Error: Expected a value of type 'Element', but got one of type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject'
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw*
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 99:3        castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 452:10  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 635:14     as_C
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 11786:34                              _get
dart-sdk/lib/collection/list.dart 263:23                                          toList
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 11803:46                              get iterator
dart-sdk/lib/collection/list.dart 76:52                                           iterator]
packages/wakelock_web/src/import_js_library.dart 64:27                            _isLoaded
packages/wakelock_web/src/import_js_library.dart 57:10                            _isImported

The app never loads, and I see a blank screen.

Here is what my Flutter doctor command says:
[image: flutter doctor]

It appears this is a new bug. Any help would be grateful!